# python : turn structured but scattered data into gridded data without interpolating - fast

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mesh

I have a dataframe of data which contains x y and z coordinates and various scalar values.

The data is actually from a structured mesh, in the sense that all coordinates define rectangular grid cells with constant x and y spacing (not necessarily equal). The goal, is to plot the data using tricontourf for a contour map (this is no issue) and then add streamlines using the matplotlib streamplot function.

The only issue, is streamplot requires a `np.meshgrid` format grid for the coordinates, u, and v.

So I need an efficient way of convert my scattered data into a meshgrid format WITHOUT using `scipy.interpolate.griddata`.

Currently I have two ideas on how to do this (one being using griddata...)

Assume my dataframe looks like this:

```
print(thresh)

               x          y     z         f         u         v         w         r
616968  522625.0  5043701.5  3.75  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
616969  522629.0  5043701.5  3.75  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
616970  522633.0  5043701.5  3.75  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
616971  522637.0  5043701.5  3.75  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
616972  522641.0  5043701.5  3.75  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

Note that this is a slice in the z-direction, i.e. all z-coordinates are the same.

1)

```
xmin = thresh['x'].min()
xmax = thresh['x'].max()
xstep = np.diff(thresh['x'])[0]
ymin = thresh['y'].min()
ymax = thresh['y'].max()
ystep = np.diff(thresh['y'])[0]
mg = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xmin, xmax+xstep, xstep), np.arange(ymin, ymax+ystep, ystep))
u = griddata(thresh[['x', 'y']].values, thresh['u'].values, (mg[0], mg[1]), method='linear')
v = griddata(thresh[['x', 'y']].values, thresh['v'].values, (mg[0], mg[1]), method='linear')
```

2. 

```
mg = np.meshgrid(np.unique(thresh['x']), np.unique(thresh['y']))
u = np.zeros(mg[0].shape)
v = np.zeros(mg[0].shape)
for row in range(u.shape[0]):
    for col in range(u.shape[1]):
        idx = np.where((thresh['x']==mg[0][row,col]) & (thresh['y']==mg[1][row,col]))[0].item()
        u[row,col] = thresh.iloc[idx]['u']
        v[row,col] = thresh.iloc[idx]['v']
```

from this I can now do my plotting as desired:

```
#note I have cut out some pointless code here
cut = (slice['r'] <= 0.003).values #data to NOT plot in contour
triang = Triangulation(thresh['x'], thresh['y'])
mask1 = np.all(np.where(cut[triang.triangles], True, False), axis=1)
triang.set_mask(mask1)
cnt = ax.tricontourf(triang, thresh['r'])
ax.streamplot(mg[0], mg[1], u, v)
```

[image: final plot]

ANy ideas on how to make the meshgrid-ing step more efficient would be greatly appreciated, or if there is an easier way to get to my end goal

Comment: Why can you not sort on x (primary key) and y (secondary key) and then reshape the u and v vectors into the required array?

Comment: Thanks I actually ended up doing that lol